# Sales of equipment using hardware that uses OSS developed by the supplier

Tags: open-source-software

Suppose that a company (CoA) develops and sells equipment which comes with a software system (SysA) to run it. This equipment is built using associated hardware (HwB) developed by another company (CoB).

Suppose that the company (CoB) developing this associated hardware  is running it using SysB, which is open source software (OSS), specifically SysB is provided under an MIT license. Suppose that SysA does not link the binary of SysB. Suppose that SysB has a  GUI, and displays the license text. However, SysB's GUI is hidden inside the equipment and the customer usually cannot see it.

In such a case, is CoA redistributing SysB? Must CoA  present the license to the customer, eithe when SysA runs, or as part of the documentatuion, or in some other way ?

Comment: Ask your company's legal department, or hire a lawyer.

Comment: as edited, I do not think this is a request for specific legal advice, and IMO it should not be closed on that basis.